# How to have a primary key with a different name than "Id"

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following situation in my ASP.NET Core application with Entity Framework Core 1.1

**Database-Table named "Content"**

- Content_ID (int not null, primary key)
- Title (varchar max)
- Description (varchar max)

**Model ("ContentEntry.cs"):**

```cs
public class ContentEntry
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

**Configuration File (ContentEntryConfiguration.cs)**

```cs
public class ContentEntryConfiguration : IEntityMappingConfiguration<ContentEntry>
{
    public void Map(EntityTypeBuilder<ContentEntry> modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasKey(m => m.Id);

        modelBuilder.Property(m => m.Id).HasColumnName("Content_ID");
        modelBuilder.Property(m => m.Title ).HasColumnName("Title");
        modelBuilder.Property(m => m.Description).HasColumnName("Description");

        modelBuilder.ToTable("Content");
    }
}
```

As mentioned above, the primary key of my table is named "Content_ID".
When I execute a LINQ query, I receive an error saying that **the column "ID" hasn't been found on the database**. After inspecting the generated query with the SQL Profiler, I noticed that the query contains "ID" instead of "Content_ID". 
I expect entity framework to generate a query containing the column "Column_ID" instead and map it to my model-property named "Id".

Do you have an idea why this is happening and how I could fix this issue?

Comment: @Kris i corrected it; it was just a typing error, but not the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I just forgot to register the entity mapping in my DB Context Class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.RegisterEntityMapping<ContentEntry, ContentEntryConfiguration>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For people with simpler needs, this will suffice

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ContentEntry>().Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("Content_ID");
}
```